# Radio Groups in Android

Tags: android

I've been following the android documentation for RadioGroups (below for reference).

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radio_pirates:
            if (checked)
                // Pirates are the best
            break;
        case R.id.radio_ninjas:
            if (checked)
                // Ninjas rule
            break;
    }
}
```

However, I noticed that in their example, each button is associated with an `onRadioButtonClicked` function. What if I don't want anything to be triggered on each click of the radio button but only when another `Button` is clicked?

The approach that I can think of is calling `isChecked()` on each radio button. However, this seems wordy. Is there a better way or more directed way of finding the id of the radio button that has been checked in a radio group in Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [RadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html#getCheckedRadioButtonId%28%29) to get Id of checked item.